# Crop fails to work as expected on iOS8 Photos app

Tags: ipad, ios, photos.app

I'm struggling to do a simple edit on a photo in the standard Photos app on the new iOS8.

Basically, I can select a crop area, but the resulting saved photo doesn't match the area that I chose.  Here is a walk through example using screenshots of the steps I took:

First, a photo I just took as seen in the Photos app :

[image: http://cl.ly/image/3I2n392Q2M1k]

Now, I have clicked the `Edit` button from the previous photo, and applied a crop mask to trim the photo to the selected area. I've centred this on my nose :

[image: http://cl.ly/image/0w37080K2W1e]

I click `Done` in the previous picture, and the resulting saved image doesn't match what I just did, and is now centred on my left eye :

[image: http://cl.ly/image/1W032N3K050F]

Any clues?  I note it only seems to happen on photos taken with the front facing camera, worked fine on a portion of screen shot, and also on a rear facing photo...

Can anyone reproduce? (If so, can you state what you used, e.g. the same iPad 3, or Mini or whatever)

Comment: Heh - I can't reproduce that. The dude looks a lot different on my crop.

Comment: Is your crop accurate after you save the edit though?  I realise my dude may look more handsome than yours, but it's the accuracy I need to check, not the hot or not rating ;)

Comment: I get the same results on a different photo of mine. This stinks!

Comment: Not just me then - phew!

Comment: I have a cropping problem on my iPad 3 in iOS8. It's fine cropping a pic taken with the front facing camera. However, if I crop a pic grabbed off the internet, the area it saves is totally different to what I had selected.

Comment: I've not tried a grabbed photo.  Can you check if your rear camera and screenshot pics (hold home then press lock to take a screenshot) work as normal?  I'll grab a pic off the net and try

Comment: Ok, rear facing pic, takes and crops just fine. Same for a screen grab. BUT picture saved off the internet will not crop accurately. I tried to upload the pictures here to show the difference, but it's taking forever (everything is slower with iOS8) and my patience is wearing thin!;-)

Comment: Are you sure your internet is fine?

Comment: Yes definitely! :-)

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce that behavior. All kidding aside about handsomeness - I'm getting the expected crop on all "selfie" camera shots.

I've tested on the original iPhone mini and iPhone 5 with iOS 8 so far.

It's almost like a retina bug where it's counting pixels instead of points. Perhaps it's a 2x error that needs to be reported to Apple if you can reproduce it on another device that's the same hardware as yours.

Comment: The scale seems right, it more seems like the exif is wrong, like it's showing me portrait then cropping landscape, or something.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this is indeed a bug, that can be reproduced by various other people.  There's nothing I am doing wrong, it's just not working.  I have submitted a bug report to Apple.  If you get this issue too, then please report it [here](http://www.apple.com/feedback/) or [here](http://bugreport.apple.com/).  The more reports they get, the faster it may get fixed.